# Broke laptop screen, trying to use usable region

Tags: windows-7, video, drivers, resolution, pan

I recently broke my laptop screen, and now 1" of the right side is unusable.  I'd like to be able to use the laptop without always manually resizing windows to keep them away from this region.

I was able to get a partial solution by reducing the resolution, and then forcing the driver to "center" the screen, which effectively prevents the panel from scaling and giving me those awful blurry pixels.

This gets me about 80% of the way there.  While now much of the broken region is not in use, a small portion still is, and I would like to be able to shift the display.  I looked around for panning options and googled it, but that just brings up information about virtual displays.  I am not interested in a virtual desktop.  I just want the exact pixels that are in use in the center of the screen to be shifted, just like how televisions can do it.

Can anyone tell me how to make this happen in Windows 7?

Comment: I think the panning you're looking for is going to be a hardware option of some sort. I am not certain that there are many (if any) laptops out there that support what you are proposing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Gridmove](http://jgpaiva.dcmembers.com/gridmove.html) or some other software that does slightly finer grained aerosnap style window management, and snaps windows to a grid, might work - you'd probably need to create a snap to area the same size as your damaged section, and well, not use that. If that dosen't work, i'd suggest taking a look at [gridy](http://sector-seven.net/software/gridy) or some other [alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/gridy/)

Its a workaround, but it seems to be an 'easier' option than messing with resolutions and other things at driver level.